# Looking for alternatives to the microstrain_3dmgx2_imu?

Tags: ros, imu, driver, microstrain

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for alternative IMUs for our autonomous robot. However, the driver must support ROS. It has been pretty difficult to find different ones since I am new to building robots but I'm trying to research alternatives.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186984/looking-for-alternatives-to-the-microstrain_3dmgx2_imu?/) by [faceinthegrass](https://answers.ros.org/users/19773/faceinthegrass/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can look for Xsens IMU's.

http://www.xsens.com/products/mti/

http://www.xsens.com/products/mti-g-700/

http://www.xsens.com/products/mti-10-series/

http://www.xsens.com/products/mti-100-series/

ROS Driver for XSens MT/MTi/MTi-G devices is available at http://wiki.ros.org/xsens_driver

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1